# python variable not defined

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Hi I am flowing [this](https://electrosome.com/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-sensor-raspberry-pi/) tutorial but in python code I always get

```
NameError: name 'pulse_start' is not defined
```

error. What is wrong, what do you suggest ? thanks.

Comment: @ReutSharabani so, what should I change/add ?

Comment: `pulse_start` is assigned a value only if `while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:` evaluates to true. Have you tried stepping through your program and seeing if it enters the `while` loop?

Comment: how are we going to help without seeing the code?

Comment: @eigenchris I am checking now..

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I linked above

Comment: @user1798028, You should add the relevant part of the code to your question

Comment: @eigenchris, I just mixed the ground pin, so it's working now, if you write your answer above I can thick it

Comment: Everyone, thank you for your help, it was mymistake about pins thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pulse_start` is assigned a value only if `GPIO.input(ECHO)==0` evaluates to true. Have you tried stepping through your program and seeing if it enters the while loop?

In general, `x is not defined` errors occur when the variable `x` has not been initialized with a value and the program tries to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a reference to a variable called `pulse_start`, but you never defined it, so the interpreter isn't sure what you're talking about. Define it before using it.